# Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined

Tags: android, cordova

This is my HelloPlugin.js file.

```
var HelloPlugin = { 
  callNativeFunction: function(success,fail,resultType) { 
    return cordova.exec(success, fail, "HelloPlugin", "nativeAction", [resultType]); 
  } 
};
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
: Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/HelloPlugin.js:3
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add cordove.js into your code

Comment: cordova.js is not my file. Its the PhoneGap file that I have copied to www/assets folder

Comment: add this line <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pleas make sure you have `<script ...` tag for *cordova.js* before `<script ...` tag for *HelloPlugin.js* in your HTML file.

It should have both in the `<head>` tag like this:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="HelloPlugin.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in iOS. The solution was to install [`cordova-plugin-file-transfer2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-transfer2#sample):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```